# Django model inheritance: how to retrieve records?

Tags: django, inheritance

I have these Django models:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Restaurant(Base):
    pass

class Hotel(Base)
    pass

class Message(models.Model)
    text = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Base, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to set up a query to retrieve all of the messages left about Hotels only. But how to do that?

```
Message.objects.filter(has_attr("Hotel"))
```

Obviously this doesn't work but something like that is what I am looking for.

Comment: `Message.objects.filter(parent__hotel__isnull=False)`?

Comment: That's it!! Who knew it could be so simple?! Can you add this as an answer to accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inherited model has an implicit `OneToOneField` from the child to the parent. This relation in reverse has, by default, as related name the name of the class, so `hotel`.

We thus can check if there exists a `Hotel` object for the given `parent` with:

```
Message.objects.filter(parent__hotel__isnull=False)
```